# Showing New Products on home page from Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product-collection

I am trying to show New Products on the home page from Magento 2, for this, I am written below code. But I am not getting correct data. between `$from_date = strtotime('12/28/2016');` and `$to_date = strtotime('01/30/2017');` dates.

```
/**
     * Get product collection
     */
    public function getProducts() {

        $from_date = strtotime('12/28/2016');
        $to_date = strtotime('01/30/2017');

        $news_from_date = $this->_localeDate->date($from_date)->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $news_to_date = $this->_localeDate->date($to_date)->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $collection =  $this->_collection
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
        ->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
                'news_from_date',
                [
                    'or' => [
                        0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $news_from_date],
                        1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                    ]
                ],
                'left'
            )
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'news_to_date',
                [
                    'or' => [
                        0 => ['date' => true, 'from' => $news_to_date],
                        1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                    ]
                ],
                'left'
            )->addAttributeToFilter(
                [
                    ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                    ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                ]
            );
        return $collection;
    }
```

Could you please suggest me how to get the product collection between two dates?

Comment: added answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
public function getProducts() {

            $from_date = strtotime('12/28/2016');
            $to_date = strtotime('01/30/2017');

            $news_from_date = $this->_localeDate->date($from_date)->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $news_to_date = $this->_localeDate->date($to_date)->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $collection =  $this->_collection
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
            ->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
                    'news_from_date',
                    [
                        'or' => [
                            0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $news_to_date],
                            1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                        ]
                    ],
                    'left'
                )
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    'news_to_date',
                    [
                        'or' => [
                            0 => ['date' => true, 'from' => $news_from_date],
                            1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                        ]
                    ],
                    'left'
                )->addAttributeToFilter(
                    [
                        ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                        ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                    ]
                );
            return $collection;
        }
```

Let me know if it work for you. i just reversed from and to date

Comment: Let's try it... wait..

Comment: @magentotwo any luck ?

Comment: not yet tried I am in another work. I will back once I tried. Thanks You.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to add the widget on home page.

1) Click on Content from sidebar

2) Then click on Pages you see the list of all pages

3) Select Home Page and edit it

4) Then click on content and if you cant see the editor like attached image clcik on **Show / Hide Editor**

5) Then there you can see the insert widget icon then click on it and add the widget that you want to show on homepage.

For more follow the screenshot

[image]